# Routing error after user session is created ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Evening, I have been working on this issue for few hours now and I can't seem to find a fix for it(noob on RoR). Long story short - after creating a user session and the user is logged in, I can't switch to different pages. This is the error that comes up: [The error after I try viewing a different html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkGDP.jpg)

**users_controller.rb** :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end



  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)


      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to CarsOnGo #{@user.username}"
        redirect_to users_path
      else
       render 'new'
      end
    end


  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email,:password,:image)
    end
end
```

**show.html.erb**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row profile">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="profile-sidebar">
                <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <div class="profile-userpic">
                    <center><%= image_tag("taho1.JPG", :alt => "rss feed") %></center>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                <div class="profile-usertitle">
                    <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
                        <%= @user.username %>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                <div class="profile-userbuttons">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Message</button>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
                <div class="profile-usermenu">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                            Overview </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                            Account Settings </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="images">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            Upload Vehicle Info</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
                            Help </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- END MENU -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="profile-content">
              <%= form_for(@user, multipart: true) do |f| %>

                      <div class="field">
                        <%= f.label :picture %>
                        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="actions">
                        <%= f.submit 'Upload Image' %>

                      </div>
                    <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<center>

</center>
<br>
<br>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :images
  resources :vehicles
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'sessions/destory'

   resource :users 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'newcars', to: 'vehicles#new'

  get 'signup', to: 'users#new'
  get 'profile', to: 'pages#profile' 
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'images', to: 'images#new'
  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy' 


  resources :users, except: [:new]
  end
```

Comment: The routes are also included in show html page. Thank you for your assistance and time, i highly appreciate it.

Comment: can you share the code snipet from where you are trying to visit `user/show` page ?

Comment: Couldn't find user with 'id' = newcars. But It's good if I can see full url

Answer (score 0):

In your `users_controller.rb`

```
# POST /users
# POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to CarsOnGo #{@user.username}"
      redirect_to user_path(@user) # <----- This part should look like this
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Note: notice the `path` and the `user object`